# Use constant as property name in a template

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm using **vuex** and have separated file for getter names constants. What is a best practice to use that constant inside *.vue file template?

// getter-types.js

```js
export const CURRENT_USER_NAME = 'CURRENT_USER_NAME'
```

// store.js

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    userName: ''
  },
  getters: {
    [CURRENT_USER_NAME]: state => {
      return state.userName
    }
  },
  // ...
})
```

Here I use solution with **_self** keyword. May I use something else and have possibility change value in **getter-types.js** without any errors.

// index-page.vue

```html
<template>
<div>Hello, it works: {{_self[constants.CURRENT_USER_NAME]}}</div>
<div>Hello, it doesn't when I edit constant value later: {{CURRENT_USER_NAME}}</div>
<div>Hello, {{ ??? }}</div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
import { CURRENT_USER_NAME } from './getter-types'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      constants: { // I can't use constant name directly, so create object
        CURRENT_USER_NAME
      }
    }
  },
  created () {
    console.log(this[CURRENT_USER_NAME]) // works fine
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
      CURRENT_USER_NAME
    ])
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: you couldn't modify constants

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim I mean getter-types.js file values

Comment: how do you change them?